# apache2 not picking up TNS_ADMIN environmental variable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.4, oracle, environment-variables

I am trying to set 2 environmental variables for use in apache:

- LD_LIBRARY_PATH
- TNS_ADMIN.

I set these in: /etc/apache2/envvars

The former is picked up and set correctly, but the latter is not. I've tried setting a few random variable names as well and they don't seem to be picked up either so it looks like this is only used for certain environmental variables? If so, what would be the best way to set this variable for use in apache?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is best practice, but I've managed to set the environmental variables in the following file: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

To set an environmental variable you use the following syntax:

```
SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /some/folder/path/here
SetEnv TNS_ADMIN /another/folder/path/here
```